# Difference between tags virus, malware, trojan, infection,worm

Tags: discussion, tags

From most used to least used (including related tags):

- [virus](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virus) x 501

  - [anti-virus](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/anti-virus) x 453
  - [virus-removal](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virus-removal) x 56
- [malware](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/malware) x 256

  - [malware-removal](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/malware-removal) x 37
  - [malware-detection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/malware-detection) x 13
  - [anti-malware](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/anti-malware) x 11
- [trojan](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/trojan) x 70
- [infection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/infection) x 8
- [worm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/worm) x 8

Are they really unique? I know that they might be a little bit different by definition, but are they different enough for users that aren't experts on the subject?

Comment: You mean Super Users are not expert enough to need the definitions between them?

Comment: @HaydnWVN I'm sure that's not what they meant. But new users here might be confused by the different tags.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about new/inexperienced users, that for them all those tags look like synonyms.

Comment: I respectfully disagree.  There *is* a difference; however small a new/inexperienced user might think it is, indeed it's a *huge* technical difference.  I think the only "questionable" tags above are `malware` (which technically encompasses all the other tags), and `infection`.

Comment: @Breakthrough I understand. I just wanted to make sure the tag wikis are clear enough for inexperienced users and that none of them are useless (I thought we could get rid of `[worm]` or `[infection]` but I don't really know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm of the opinion that for many OP's (who are usually 'basic' users asking for help with an 'technical' (virus/malware type) problem) the exact distinction may be very confusing (and probably unknown).

I still feel the multiple tags should be available - yet users who are not knowledgeable enough to define their explicit problem should be encouraged to use the [malware](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/malware) or [virus](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virus) tags.

Questions can then be edited/improved (by the OP or more likely other editors) to make the distinction.

Remember that many original questions may not contain enough information to diagnose the exact cause/'infection' until more in-depth diagnosis steps from comments/questions are taken anyway.